# Matlab Error using load Bad version or endian-key

Tags: matlab, distributed-computing

I have been trying to load a mat file on my distributed computing environment. When I load running in a matlab terminal on any computer I can load it no problem. When I submit it as a job to my cluster it fails saying

```
Error using load
Bad version of endian-key
```

even though the version of matlab is identical. Just the environment is changed. I have stripped away everything to just simply

```
load ~/Desktop/model.mat
disp('Done');
exit;
```

and the problem persists. We are running this using Sun Grid Engine.

Comment: Messages 7 and 9 in [this MATLAB Central thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/336885) might be useful. And possibly [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592602/bad-version-or-endian-key-in-matlab-parfor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular error message can either mean the file is corrupted, or it can mean that the system failed to allocate memory while loading the data (and no, that isn't obvious from the message...)

Comment: It was memory allocation. Thanks!